# GCP Sign up issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am facing some issues while setting up a Free google cloud platform sign-up.
The error message that I am observing while setting up a free GCP are as follows
"An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR-BSBBF-103]".to create a new billing account

Comment: If you google that error code it comes up with an abundance of information. What have you tried to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hey tried adding different google account, even the money is deducted from the account but still the issue persist with the same error message